# Switched browsers, now getting native host connector not detected

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

I switched from Google Chrome to Firefox. Now I get this error.

> Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector.

It worked perfectly on Chrome.

When I try to install chrome-gnome-shell, I get this message.

```
chrome-gnome-shell:  
Installed: 10.1-1  
Candidate: 10.1-1  
Version table:  *** 10.1-1  
500 500 http://uk-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe amd64 Packages   
500 http://uk-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu cosmic/universe i386 Packages  
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status N: Unable to locate package install
```

Comment: https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/

Comment: For me it in contrast did not work in Chrome, but worked only in Firefox

Answer (score 0):

To save time you can skip the first part of this answer, and scroll down to the **Ubuntu 18.04 and later** section and start from there.

> In order to install extensions a web browser, you need two things: a
>   browser add-on and a native host connector in your system.
>
> 1. When you visit the [GNOME Shell Extensions website](https://extensions.gnome.org/), you'll see a message like
>      this:
>
>    > To control GNOME Shell extensions using this site you must install GNOME Shell integration that consists of two parts: browser extension
>    >     and native host messaging application.
>
>    Click the link that says *Click here to install browser extension*.
> 2. Just installing browser add-on won't help you. You'll still see an error like:
>
>    > Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about
>    >     installing connector.
>
>    This is because you haven't installed the host connector yet. To do that, use this command:
>
>    ```
>    sudo apt install chrome-gnome-shell
>    ```

<sup>**Source:** [How to use GNOME Shell Extensions](https://itsfoss.com/gnome-shell-extensions/)</sup>

---

The above instructions are provided for information purposes only because there is a much better way of doing the same thing in Ubuntu Software in Ubuntu 18.04 and later. If you try the below method of installing GNOME Shell Extensions you will find that it is much faster and more convenient.

### Ubuntu 18.04 and later

In Ubuntu 18.04 and later GNOME Shell Extensions can be installed from the Ubuntu Software app. Do a keyword search for "GNOME shell extensions" and the type of app you are searching for.

You can also search from all of the available GNOME Shell Extensions on the same screen by pressing Add-ons button which is located under the **Categories** heading. In the Add-ons screen select the *Shell Extensions* tab and you will see all the available GNOME Shell Extensions.

[image]

- Clicking on a GNOME Shell Extension in the list of search results will bring up its screen which will often show screenshot(s).
- Clicking on the       <kbd>Website</kbd>        button will open its website in a web browser where you can view a larger sized image of the same screenshot that was shown in Ubuntu Software.
- Clicking on the         <kbd>Install</kbd>          button will install the extension.